# Create complex argument-driven queries from AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-appsync

Look for `// HERE IS THE PROBLEM PART` sentence to find code that is the problem.

I am trying to implement AppSync using AWS Lambda (that connects to RDS Postgres server) as a data source. I want to create `puKnowledgeFile` query that will update my `KnowledgeFile` with optional arguments. If the client only provided `htmlText` and `properties` as arguments, then my `update` query should only update these two fields.

```
type Mutation {
    putKnowledgeFile(
        id: ID!,
        htmlText: String,
        plainText: String,
        properties: AWSJSON
    ): KnowledgeFile
}

type KnowledgeFile {
    id: ID!
    htmlText: String!
    plainText: String!
    properties: AWSJSON!
    lastDateTimeModified: AWSDateTime!
    dateTimeCreated: AWSDateTime!
}
```

Here is an piece of AWS Lambda code:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  
  /* Connecting to Postgres */

  let data = null;
  let query = ``;
  let values = [];
  
  switch (event.info.fieldName) {
    case "putKnowledgeFile":
      if(event.arguments.htmlText === undefined &&
         event.arguments.plainText === undefined &&
         event.arguments.properties === undefined) {
        callback(`At least one argument except id should be provided in putKnowledgeFile request`);
      }

      // HERE IS THE PROBLEM PART
      query += `update knowledge_file`

      query += `
      set `;
      
      let index = 0;
      for (let fieldName in event.arguments) {
        if(arguments.hasOwnProperty(fieldName)) {
          const fieldValue = event.arguments[fieldName];
    
          if(index === 0) {
            query += `${fieldName}=$${index+1}`
            values.push(fieldValue);
          } else {
            query += `, ${fieldName}=$${index+1}`
            values.push(fieldValue);
          }
    
          index++;
        }
      }

      query += `
where knowledge_file.id = $${index+1};`;
      values.push(event.arguments.id);
      // HERE IS THE PROBLEM PART

        break;
    default:
      callback(`There is no functionality to process this field: ${event.info.fieldName}`);
      return;
  }
  
  let res = null;
  try {
    res = await client.query(query, values); // just sending created query
  } catch(error) {
    console.log("@client.query");
    console.log(error);
  }

  /* DisConnecting from Postgres */

  callback(null, res.rows);

};
```

Basically, this algorithm creates my query string through multiple string concatenations. I think it's too complicated and error-prone. **Is there a way to create dynamic queries based on the presence / absence of certain arguments easily?**

Just in case, here is my PostgreSQL schema:

```
-- main client object for clients
CREATE TABLE client (
  id bigserial primary key,
  full_name varchar(255)
);

-- knowledge_file
create table knowledge_file (
  id bigserial primary key,
  html_text text,
  plain_text text,
  properties jsonb,
  last_date_modified timestamptz,
  date_created timestamptz,
  word_count varchar(50)
);

-- which client holds which knowledge file
create TABLE client_knowledge_file (
  id bigserial primary key,
  client_id bigint not null references client(id),
  knowledge_file_id bigint not null references knowledge_file(id) unique ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use Lambda to connect to your RDS instance since you can directly connect your AppSync API to your RDS?

Comment: You mean using Aurora Serverless Data API? Well, then I would need to do similar logic in the mapping templates, and it seems like it will be more convenient to use JS instead of VTL. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. How have you defined these in your RDS? Are these null-able fields?

Comment: Can you please clarify, what do you mean by "these"?

Comment: Sorry. I mean how have you defined these field (`htmlText` & `properties`) in your RDS table schema?

Comment: I have created a PostgreSQL database using RDS, I aded the schema (i.e. create queries) at the bottom of my asnwer.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an optimum solution and might not completely answer your question but I also ran into similar problem and this is how I solved it.

1. I created a resolver pipeline.
2. In one function, I used the `select` statement to get the current
   record.
3. In second function, I checked if the fields (in your case `htmlText` and `properties`) are null. If true, then use the `ctx.prev.result` values otherwise use the new ones).

**Practical example**

First resolver function:

```
{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "select id, html_text AS \"htmlText\", plain_text AS \"plainText\", properties, last_date_modified AS \"lastDateTimeModified\", date_created AS \"dateTimeCreated\" from knowledge_file where id = $ctx.args.Id"
    ]
}
```

Second resolver function:

```
#set($htmlText = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.htmlText , $ctx.prev.result.htmlText))
#set($properties = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.args.properties , $ctx.prev.result.properties))


{
    "version": "2018-05-29",
    "statements": [
        "update knowledge_file set html_text = $htmlText, plain_text = $ctx.args.plainText, properties = $properties, last_date_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, date_created = CURRENT_DATE where id = $ctx.args.Id returning id, html_text AS \"htmlText\", plain_text AS \"plainText\", properties, last_date_modified AS \"lastDateTimeModified\", date_created AS \"dateTimeCreated\""
    ]
}
```